# Prevent gnome from changing the workspace on focus when using multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, window-focus

Currently I'm using two monitors, one for exclusively viewing and editing code, another for doing everything else. I have hotkeys set up to focus on either `sublime`, or `firefox` or the `terminal` like this:

`C-M-1` executes `wmctrl -a firefox` \

`C-M-2` executes `wmctrl -a sublime` -- via the default gnome-shortcuts.

`C-M-3` executes `wmctrl -a konsole` /

The problem is, when I change the focus to `sublime` (placed on my extended display), my workspace on the other monitor automatically switches to the workspace that had focus when `sublime` was originally opened (usually, my `terminal` workspace). This means that when I want to use `firefox` and `sublime`, I need to to change on which workspace `firefox` lives on. Is there a quick fix for this?

*Changing the focus by clicking into `sublime` does not change which workspace I'm at on the primary monitor.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I've understood what you want but from what I gather, you need Firefox to stay on the extended monitor, and change workspace on the base monitor to go from Sublime to Terminal (or more).

That's fairly straightforward as GNOME's default configuration should not create workspaces on the secondary monitor. In GNOME Tweak Tool, go to workspaces and set `Workspaces only on primary display` to `On`, that should take care of the problem and keep Firefox on the secondary display even when switching workspace on the main display.

Comment: Well, I only have one workspace on the extended display, but when I focus to the application on the extended display using ```wmctrl``` changes my workspace on the primary display.